# QGIS 2.4.0 marker line interval does not work properly when line is bending

Tags: qgis, line, markers

I am trying to style a line using marker line option. When I am using styling the line in the style window everything looks nice as you can see on the print screen bellow.

[image: line layer properties]

I am using three line features (units are mm):

- simple line: dash pattern 7 2
- marker line: interval 9
- marker line: interval 9, offset 5

However the result in QGIS looks horrible as shown on the next picture. Could somebody tell me how to avoid this? It looks like QGIS is not properly listening to the dash pattern and interval settings.

[image: QGIS result]

Comment: I guess the rotation and xy offset of the marker does not work when the line is not parallel to X or Y. Can you try a marker without rotation and offset?

Comment: Is your error scale dependent? Does it worsen/correct itself on different map scales?

Comment: To AndreJ: unfortunatelly it does not work even when I don't use any rotation or offset

Comment: To til_b: it remains the same on different scales

Comment: Are those lines a single feature?

Comment: the lines that are on the pictures are two features. but is does not work also for the single feature line

Comment: Just one more chance: In your screenshot, the anchor point is left, VCenter. Can you change that too?

Comment: There is no improvement when I changed it :( it looks like the interval of the dashed line would not correspond to the interval of the marker. But they are both in same units (mm) and all the settings looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not the perfect solution, but I created SVG marker with the required symbology.

[image: SVG marker]

Then I set the needed interval and finally it works how I want!

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1):

I took the same style values as you, and it looks quite good:

[image]

but it looks better with a svg symbol. With the standard `>` I get this:

[image]

The saved style looks as follows:

```
  <renderer-v2 symbollevels="0" type="singleSymbol">
    <symbols>
      <symbol alpha="1" type="line" name="0">
        <layer pass="0" class="SimpleLine" locked="0">
          <prop k="capstyle" v="square"/>
          <prop k="color" v="99,5,130,255"/>
          <prop k="customdash" v="7;2"/>
          <prop k="customdash_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="customdash_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="draw_inside_polygon" v="0"/>
          <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="penstyle" v="solid"/>
          <prop k="use_custom_dash" v="1"/>
          <prop k="width" v="0.26"/>
          <prop k="width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="width_unit" v="MM"/>
        </layer>
        <layer pass="0" class="MarkerLine" locked="0">
          <prop k="interval" v="9"/>
          <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
          <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
          <symbol alpha="1" type="marker" name="@0@1">
            <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
              <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
              <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
              <prop k="color_border" v="0,0,0,255"/>
              <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
              <prop k="name" v="arrowhead"/>
              <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
              <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="scale_method" v="area"/>
              <prop k="size" v="2"/>
              <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
            </layer>
          </symbol>
        </layer>
        <layer pass="0" class="MarkerLine" locked="0">
          <prop k="interval" v="9"/>
          <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line" v="5"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
          <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
          <symbol alpha="1" type="marker" name="@0@2">
            <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
              <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
              <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
              <prop k="color_border" v="0,0,0,255"/>
              <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
              <prop k="name" v="arrowhead"/>
              <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
              <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="scale_method" v="area"/>
              <prop k="size" v="2"/>
              <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0"/>
              <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
            </layer>
          </symbol>
        </layer>
      </symbol>
    </symbols>
    <rotation/>
    <sizescale scalemethod="area"/>
  </renderer-v2>
```